# Google Maps API bug?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I built a web app where I'm using the Google API. Yesterday it worked fine but today I can't see the map anymore, just a grey background. The geo coordinates are fine and all the markers are in good position but the map isn't loading.

Is it something related to the API? Has anyone experienced this? Might be due to a cross-domain or policy issue?

Comment: Stab in the face for "working good"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found that is may be due to the v= speficied

so you should use v=3.3

```
<script src="https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.3&sensor=false"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is valid remember:

- You don't need set the api version.
- If you use: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js` you just adds the **key** as a parameter.
- Resulting in: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY"`

Probably, the problem will be solved when you put a valid key.

How you register and get one key, you can see here: https://console.developers.google.com

I hope help you!